# UWP Window hangs with Monogame

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, monogame

I just tried to create a new `UWP` App referencing: `MonoGame.Framework.WindowsUniversal 3.6.0.1625`, and Targeting `Windows 10 Creators Update (10.0; Build 15063)`.

I think I did everything right to "bootstrap" a `: Game` from the `SwapChainPanel`:

I put `<SwapChainPanel x:Name="swapChainPanel" />` in my `Page`
I put this in codebehind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    readonly Game1 _game;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Create the game.
        var launchArguments = string.Empty;
        _game = MonoGame.Framework.XamlGame<Game1>.Create(launchArguments, Window.Current.CoreWindow, swapChainPanel);
        _game.Run();
    }
}
```

And my `Game1 : Game` is just the same as Monogame templates.

When I start the application, there are no exceptions and the whole window hangs on the "UWP SplashScreen" (when it shows you the icon of your app) and nothing happens. My `Draw` method just clears the screen with red, just to see it working, but it doesn't.

Am I missing something?

[I attached a very simple project to show that.](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/files/1188964/App2.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem was calling: `_game.Run();`.

By reading the source code on [Github](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/WindowsUniversal/XamlGame.cs), I saw that the method:

```
static public T Create(string launchParameters, CoreWindow window, SwapChainPanel swapChainPanel)
```

already called `Run`:

```
   // Start running the game.
   game.Run(GameRunBehavior.Asynchronous);
```

By removing my call to the `Run` method, everything worked.